# Running ps script in different subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a script I want to run in several subfolders in the same directory that have the same structure. I have the variables $pdfPath, $pdfoutpath, and $newFolder. How can I change the variables to look in folderA\input, folderB\input, folderc\input, ect? I've tried using wildcards but that did not work. I can't use just 'C:\path*' because I need to separate the output.

Thanks for any input :)

```
$pdfPath = 'C:\path\folderA\input'
$pdfoutPath = 'C:\path\folderA\output'
$newFolder = 'C:\path\folderA\Complete'
$pdfFile = Join-Path $pdfPath '*.pdf'
$SetsOfPages = 1
$Match = 'NumberOfPages: (\d+)'
$NumberOfPages = [regex]::match((pdftk $pdfFile dump_data),$Match).Groups[1].Value
"{0,2} pages in {1}" -f $NumberOfPages, $pdfFile

for ($Page=1;$Page -le $NumberOfPages;$Page+=$SetsOfPages){
  $File = Get-Item $pdfFile
  $Range = "{1}" -f $page,[math]::min($Page+$SetsOfPages-1,$NumberOfPages)
  $OutFile = Join-Path $pdfoutPath ($File.BaseName+"_$Range.pdf")
  "processing: {0}" -f $OutFile
  pdftk $pdfFile cat $Range output $OutFile
}
Get-ChildItem $pdfPath '*.pdf' -Recurse | foreach { 
$new_folder_name = Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -uformat %V
$des_path = "${newFolder}\${new_folder_name}"

if (test-path $des_path){ 
    move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
    } else {
    new-item -ItemType directory -Path $des_path
    move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
    }
}
```

Comment: make your `$pdfPath` $Var an array of such paths. wrap everything else in a processing loop. then, in that loop, calculate the other related paths based on the current source path.

Comment: Thanks, so I need an array like $inputPath = C:\path\folderA\input,C:\path\folderB\input, ect...then I need a ForEach $inputPath loop. How do I calculate the other related paths based on the current source path?

Comment: I was looking into using a .txt file to contain lines for: folderA; folderB; folderC and equate them to the unique paths, then somehow do a ForEach to reference them like: Get-Content PDFLocal.txt | Foreach-Object{
   $var = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $pdfPath 
} but I'm having issues with the syntax.

Comment: i couldn't fit the answer to "how to calc the other paths" into this format, to i added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way to calculate the other paths from the input paths ...

```
$InputPathList = @(
    'C:\path\folder_A\input'
    'C:\path\folder_B\input'
    'C:\path\folder_C\input'
    )
$OutputRelPath = 'Output'
$CompleteRelPath = 'Complete'

foreach ($IPL_Item in $InputPathList)
    {
    $Root = Split-Path -Path $IPL_Item -Parent
    $OutPath = Join-Path -Path $Root -ChildPath $OutputRelPath
    $CompletePath = Join-Path -Path $Root -ChildPath $CompleteRelPath

    $IPL_Item
    $Root
    $OutPath
    $CompletePath
    '=' * 30
    }
```

output ...

```
C:\path\folder_A\input
C:\path\folder_A
C:\path\folder_A\Output
C:\path\folder_A\Complete
==============================
C:\path\folder_B\input
C:\path\folder_B
C:\path\folder_B\Output
C:\path\folder_B\Complete
==============================
C:\path\folder_C\input
C:\path\folder_C
C:\path\folder_C\Output
C:\path\folder_C\Complete
==============================
```